# WPF win app .HTML resource, How to path to images in the .html .resource

Tags: c#, html, wpf, embedded-resource

I have a working WPF .exe that currently pulls a .resource (.html) file into a web browser embedded control. My issue is pathing any image references within this HTML resource. All assets are local to this project and can be embedded within the project.

I am curious as to HOW to do image and or .JS references and/or best practices. I am new to WPF, so I usually work from the code side as opposed to doing things on the XAML side.

```
            Uri HTMLuri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MYPROJECT;component/Resources/help.html", UriKind.Absolute);
            Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(HTMLuri).Stream;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                this.wbHelp.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
```

I have read several articles around the web on this 'similar' topic but the contexts were not correct (necessarily) for what I'm trying to accomplish. Question: How do I path HTML assets within an .HTML .resource file in a standalone WPF Win APP? Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will most likely not be to your liking. I spent a long time trying to crack this very problem, but (unless something changed in the latest .NET 4.5 `WebBrowser` control) unfortunately, this is not possible. The reason is because this control will run in its own context with absolutely no connection to the rest of your WPF project.